# How to load tests in ghci with stack

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

I created a very simple project with stack. It contains: an executable, a library and test targets in the associated cabal file. When I load the code to ghci via stack ghci, I can't access test there, even if they are in separate module. Is there any way to use it in such a way?

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45295351/126014) you can use `stack ghci --test`. I've found that it works without problems.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try `stack ghci (your project name):(the test suite name)`. Then you should be able to enter `main` and your tests will run.

Example:

If your .cabal project file had the following values:

```
name: ExampleProject
...
test-suite Example-test
```

Then the command to run would be `stack ghci ExampleProject:Example-test`

(edit suggested by @Chris Stryczynski)

To watch the `test` and `src` directories so they are updated when you reload with `:r`, run:

```
stack ghci --ghci-options -isrc --ghci-options -itest ExampleProduct:Example-test
```

Comment: If you do this, `:r` won't reload changes to your lib. Do you know how to do it so that `:r` recompiles the lib and tests?

Comment: @SeanClarkHess There's a couple ways of setting up tests. You can set it up by adding the library you're testing to the test-suite build-depends, or you can just add the library source folder to the test-suite hs-source-dirs. I *believe* `:r` works with the latter and not the former, but I'm not certain.

Sorry for taking so long to notice your question.

Comment: I think you need to do a `stack install` of the library under test prior to running the command above, don't you?