# Why does 'stack ghci' not load my test files?

Tags: ghci, haskell-stack

I have a project structure that looks like this

[image]

Note that the 'api/test' directory contains 'Spec.hs', and 'api' is my project root directory containing my '.cabal' and '.yaml' files.

When I run `$ stack ghci` from the project root (api), `api/test/Spec.hs` is not in scope. Whereas my modules in `api/src/` are in scope.

**Why are the modules defined in `api/test` not in scope?**

My .cabal file is configured properly such that `$ stack test` is able to successfully run the code of `api/test/Spec.hs`.

I am not able to even load the `Spec.hs` module from ghci. Attempting to do so by running
`> :l test/Spec.hs` from within ghci gives many 'Failed to load interface' errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default "stack ghci" just loads the library in, not tests, executables, or benchmarks.  Use "stack ghci --test" to also try to load all tests.